# How to replace a div to give the user edit options with slide effect using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am displaying details of customers in a table format, there is an edit button if i click on that button the details of the customers must slide up and get hidden and a new div must slide up in place of the previous one so as to give the user a textbox to edit the details. How that can be achieved through jquery.. thanks

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="SlideUpDownApplication.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnpress").click(function () {
                $("#replaceDiv").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
              $("#myDiv").slideUp("fast");    //Slide Up Effect
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="button">
        <asp:Button ID="btnpress" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <p>
            Cool Read More Content Here. Lorem Ipsom. Cool Read More Content Here. Lorem Ipsom.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="replaceDiv">
        <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? can you atleast post the existing code so that we can work with it?

Comment: Put your code in  in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I have added the code above

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done in Javascript using jQuery.
In the button click even handler function you write code which:
1. Use jQuery slide up animation to slide the div containing customer details.
2. Use jQuery slide down animation to slide a div containing a textbox to edit the detail.